# only show first # words, using jquery

Tags: split, slice

i have a problem. i load some text from the db. On my page, i only want to show 30 first words of this text. I will then add a 'read more' button, which will redirect the user to a new page. So the 'jquery expander plugin', which will show the remaining text in the same div, will not work for me I think.

i got this far:

```
$content = $("#blog_1").find(".entryContent").text().split(" ");
$slicedContent = $content.slice(30);
```

I have been messing around with .split and .slice for hours. But no success. 
I don't even have to 'keep' the remainder of the text, since it will be loaded again when the user will click read more, on the 'detail page'. So onwards from word 30, the text could be removed from the DOM.
answers regarding displaying a set number of characters instead of words are also helpful.

Thanks in advace!

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question first, it's like this:

```
var test = "I have been messing around with .split and .slice for hours. But no success. I don't even have to 'keep' the remainder of the text, since it will be loaded again when the user will click read more, on the 'detail page'. So onwards from word 30, the text could be removed from the DOM. answers regarding displaying a set number of characters instead of words are also helpful."
var splittest = test.split(' ')
splittest.slice(0, 10)
(returns ["I", "have", "been", "messing", "around", "with", ".split", "and", ".slice", "for"])
```

I *would not* do this though. It's better to limit on the amount of text instead, then there is less worry about having to detect word beginnings/endings. It will also make styling easier and more predictable.

```
test.slice(0, 300)
(returns "I have been messing around with .split and .slice for hours. But no success. I don't even have to 'keep' the remainder of the text, since it will be loaded again when the user will click read more, on the 'detail page'. So onwards from word 30, the text could be removed from the DOM. answers regardi")
```

Better yet again is to limit the generation of this text server side. It's just a plain wasted of bandwidth to send all that data down and not use it.

Comment: Finnaly it works! Thank you very much for your response. I chose the second option you recommended.

Comment: I was looking for marking it as closed, but could not find where to do so.

Comment: It's the outlined tick-box next to my question, you can tick that, it will turn green, and the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$slicedContent = $content.slice(0,30)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked. Although it returned with comma's in between. I used Andrews anwer below and now my problem is solved.